# How to know which JOIN takes more time in case of multiple Joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT *  
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Condition1
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Condition2
INNER JOIN Table4 ON Condition3
INNER JOIN Table5 ON Condition4;
```

Is there a way to know which join takes more time when executing this query?

Comment: It depends on indexed columns involved.

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-explain.html) to see the execution plan

Comment: How to use Explain for Stored procedures? is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) /* your query */` to find out such details. Look at the `actual time`, but consider than the results are cumulative, that is, you have to subtract the time from the lower nodes to get the net time of a node.

You can use https://explain.depesz.com for such an execution plan, that will calculate the net time for each step for you.